# Sync data between multiple domain or ports

Tags: php, node.js, reactjs, socket.io, chatbot

Creating a Chat Widget, we're the chat widget can be hosted on any domain and the agent portal will be on the main portal.. When a chat is send from a domain it should reflect instantly on the agent portal nd vice versa.. Tried with socket.io - react & node ja but sure on syncing with multiple domains

Comment: socket.io syncs on multiple domains